# subset of critical points is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\ f: I \rightarrow ℝ$ one differentiable function, where $I$ is an open interval. If $f$ is of class $C^1$ prove that in each interval $[a, b] \subset I$, the set of critical points of $f$ belonging to $[a, b]$ is closed

i was think to prove that $\bar{A} \subset A$ where A is subset of all critical points of $[a,b]$.
So, if $c \in A$, nothing to do. Supose then $c \in \bar{A}$ and $c \notin A$

$c \notin A\Rightarrow f'(c)\neq0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \neq 0$ with $x \in A$

then i got stuck. thank you for any help

Comment: Hint: $Z=\{x:\,f'(x)=0\}=(f')^{-1}\{0\}$

Comment: What is a critical point? If it means zero slope, then you can always pick some convergent sequence of critical points $c_n \to c$ and figure out what $f'(c)$ is.